# Lightbox not closing in IE using onClick button event

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

Using Leandro Vieira Pinho's Lightbox v 0.5 code. There is a section that sets up the click event being used for closing the lightbox. This code works great in Chrome and Firefox. But when used in IE, the buttons do nothing at all. See the relevant code here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//****MISC UNRELATED CODE****//
            // Assigning click events in elements to close overlay
            $('#jquery-overlayFinancial,#jquery-lightboxFinancial').click(function () {
                _finish();
            });

        function _finish() {
            $('#jquery-lightboxFinancial').remove();
            $('#jquery-overlayFinancial').fadeOut(function () { $('#jquery-overlayFinancial').remove(); });
            // Show some elements to avoid conflict with overlay in IE. These elements appear above the overlay.
            $('embed, object, select').css({ 'visibility': 'visible' });
}

function closelightboxFinancial() {
    $('#jquery-overlayFinancial').click();
}
//****MISC UNRELATED CODE****//
</script>
```

Close Button Code on another page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function CloseMyPlan() {
        try {
            parent.closelightboxFinancial();
        }
        catch (err) {

            txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
            txt += "Error description: " + err.description + "\n\n";
            txt += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";

        }
    }

</script>
```

Close Button IMG tag on form control page:

```
<img alt="Close" style="cursor: pointer" src="<%=_imageServerPath%>images/close_btn.jpg"
        onclick="javascript:CloseMyPlan();" />
```